# Mobile site does not update "last seen" on userpage

Tags: bug, status-norepro, badges

I'll likely be without internet a little over a month from now, due to moving.  I don't want to break my (currently) 636 consecutive days visiting SciFi.SE, so I was checking my phone to make sure I could access the site just fine.

I logged in and even ended up VTCing a question.  But the "last seen" field on my profile did not update until I loaded the full site on my laptop.

Aside from that, this would seem to indicate that the "Enthusiast" and "Fanatic" badges are unavailable to mobile-only users.

Comment: Doesn't answer the actual question, but if you're on Android, there's a nifty little extension to Firefox that switches any site from mobile to desktop mode. Buzz me if you need the link.

Comment: I just tried on mobile and it updated.

Comment: Iztaka and Kevin, it might help to include the platform/version you're using.

Comment: iPhone 5/iOS 6. It's possible Izkata just got a cached page

Comment: Dolphin Browser HD 208/Android 2.1, and cached is possible but seems very unlikely - I could see the "last seen" time steadily increasing (from 5 minutes through 15 minutes) with each refresh, before refreshing on the laptop, when it reset immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this. The badges are certainly available to folks who use the mobile interface, and this is most likely a caching issue.

I just tested this with a different site and saw the "last seen" timestamp update immediately on my phone and when viewed in the browser on my desktop, but not when viewed in an incognito profile I opened up first.

Comment: K, I did some more testing myself.  It looks like it's not exactly that something was cached, but that the site will only reset the "last seen" timestamp after it's gone up a certain amount.  I did see it reset on my phone after I'd been idle for an hour, and now it's gone up even while using my laptop.   Not sure where exactly that limit is, though.